# index.php issue with codeigniter 2.1 on web server

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, codeigniter-2, codeigniter-url

I'm working on web application. In which I'm facing issue with index.php on redirect.
When even I'm submitting form to controller and redirecting to another page index.php added to URL automatically after domain name.

e.g

```
http://mydomain.com/index.php/contro/func
```

and page shows string "No input file specified."
On localhost it works very fine. Do I have some issue with hosting or with code ? Any Idea ??

Comment: In your `application/config/config.php` file did you set the `$config['index_page'] = '';` to an empty string?

Answer (score 0):

There are few things you need to set in order to make it work properly

Make sure in your `application/config/config.php` file `index_page` is set to empty

```
$config['index_page'] = '';
```

The `.htaccess` file for removing `index.php` from the url's

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L,QSA]
```

If your site is not in the root directory you may need to change this line to `RewriteBase /folder_name` where `folder_name` is the name of the folder in which you have placed your site

Comment: Yes I have same .htaccess and config setting too. I specified full path in redirect() adn now its working fine. earlier I was using just controller and function name to redirect. Thanks anyway. :)